# go test foo - cannot find package foo

Tags: go

I have this directory structure:

https://github.com/netjet-chrome-extension/netjet-mono/tree/master/examples/projects/golang

I try to run test.sh, which consists of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"
export GOPATH="$PWD"
go test sourcegraph_go_selenium
```

but I get this error:

> can't load package: package sourcegraph_go_selenium: cannot find
>   package "sourcegraph_go_selenium" in any of:
>           /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/sourcegraph_go_selenium (from $GOROOT)
>           /home/oleg/codes/netjet/netjet-mono/examples/projects/golang/src/sourcegraph_go_selenium
>   (from $GOPATH)

GOPATH is set correctly, so why can't it find the `sourcegraph_go_selenium` package? this package is right there, in `src/sourcegraph_go_selenium`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
go test sourcegraph_go_selenium/...
```